# Group rows - dynamic column names

Tags: powerquery

I need to group the table and sum with dynamic column names (which is **x** in the code)

Is there a way to do that?

This is the present list, it changes every month...

[image: this is the present list, it changes month by month]

Sample code for only two columns

```
let
Source = #"Cost Summary",
x = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"Bütçe Kodu", "Bütçe Kalemi"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Bütçe Kodu"}, {{"Sum Total", each List.Sum([Total Cost]), type number}, {"sum 2023.08", each List.Sum([2022.08]), type nullable number}, {"sum 2023.09", each List.Sum([2022.09]), type nullable number}})
in
#"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not show any data samples that can be copy/pasted, I am assuming `x` will be a `List` of the columns you wish to `Sum`.

All you need to do is **Transform** `x` into a series of aggregations in the `Table.Group` function.

eg:

```
    #"Dynamic Sums" = List.Transform(x, (li)=> {"Sum " & li, (t)=> List.Sum(Table.Column(t,li)), type number }),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Bütçe Kodu"}, #"Dynamic Sums")
in 
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: I like this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Right click and remove any columns you don't want to be part of the sum or the group

Click select the columns you want to group, right click and unpivot other columns

Click select then right click to group and use the sum operation

[image]

Code below groups on name and sums the other columns.

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"name","date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

**ALTERNATE VIEW**

Right click and remove any columns you don't want to be part of the group or the sum

Click select the columns you want to group, right click and unpivot other columns

Click select attribute column, transform ... pivot column ... , use Value for the Values column and choose Sum from Aggregate Value Function

That will add up all remaining columns dynamically.

[image]

Code below groups on name and date, and sums the other columns.

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"name","date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am sure it is working but i like the function approach more - programming-wise )))